# Why prototypes manually initialized to null still inherit from Object

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

If I write this

```
var o = Object.create(null)
alert(o instanceof Object) // this is false
```

How come this ends up being true

```
function o() {

}
o.prototype = null
alert(new o() instanceof Object) // this is true
```

Shouldn't manually setting the prototype to null cause it to inherit from nothing as Object.create does.  Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Briefly, if a constructor's prototype isn't an Object, then instances are given *Object.prototype* as their [[prototype]].

The detail is in ECMA-262, §13.2.2 [[Construct]]:

> When the [[Construct]] internal method
>   for a Function object F is called with
>   a possibly empty list of arguments,
>   the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let *obj* be a newly created native ECMAScript object.
> 2. Set all the internal methods of *obj* as specified in 8.12.
> 3. Set the [[Class]] internal property of *obj* to "**Object**".
> 4. Set the [[Extensible]] internal property of *obj* to **true**.
> 5. Let *proto* be the value of calling the [[Get]] internal property of F
>      with argument "**prototype**".
> 6. If Type(*proto*) is Object, set the [[Prototype]] internal property of *obj*
>      to *proto*.
> 7. If Type(*proto*) is not Object, set the [[Prototype]] internal property of
>      *obj* to the standard built-in Object
>      prototype object as described in
>      15.2.4.
> 8. Let *result* be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal property
>      of *F*, providing *obj* as the **this** value
>      and providing the argument list passed
>      into [[Construct]] as *args*.
> 9. If Type(*result*) is Object then return *result*.
> 10. Return *obj*.

Noting that in items 6 and 7, `null` is Type null (ECMA-262 §8.2), it is not the same as `typeof null`, which is *object*.

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate it like that, it returns an object of `o`.

Its (hidden) prototype chain *still* points to `Object`

[image: Prototype]

Comment: So I guessing the difference is the create function creates a literal equivalent of an object?

Comment: But a function will always no matter what inherent from object?

Comment: @rubixibuc A `Function` is always an `Object` in JavaScript. There is no primitive type for it.

Comment: rubixibuc - if you set a constructor's prototype to anything that isn't Type(Object), then instances constructed by it will have Object.prototype as their [[prototype]].

Comment: @RobG Which is weird, because I've found browsers erroneously say `typeof null == 'object'`.

Comment: @alex That's actually correct according to the ECMAScript specs. You could make a good case that it shouldn't be like that, but technically the browsers are right.

Comment: @Matthew I think I will [disagree](http://jsfiddle.net/UzfhJ/) with you on that one (though I'm not 100% sure). I've always considered `null` to be a primitive type, and definitely not an `Object`. If it is indeed an `Object`, it's a very funny one :P

Comment: For confusion over Type, please read my answer. `null` is Type null, howerver `typeof null == 'object'` per ECMA-262.

Comment: @RobG So `null` *is* `null`, but it is meant to report its type as `object` according to the spec. Do you know the reasoning behind that?

Comment: Alex - you'll have to ask Brendan Eich. Douglas Crockford says that JavaScript suffers from [premature standardisation](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2008/08/14/premature-standardization/), that it was [rushed to market and then instantly had a huge user base ... There was no time during its development to polish the language](http://javascript.crockford.com/remedial.html). Brendan has said similar things, I think this is an example of that.

Comment: @RobG Thanks for the clarification. @Matthew You are right and when I read your comment again I realised you didn't say `null` is an object. My bad :)